# Zebra DataWedge or EMDK on dotNet Maui

Tags: maui, .net-maui, zebra-scanners

Using a dotnet maui project im trying to scan barcodes with a zebra MC33 is there any tips or Sdk's that I can use ? ( without focusing an input please )

I did try a DW Xamarin zebra scan prject and it was pretty what i wanted but when i tried importing the file to my maui project i failed so here we are

Comment: Please post the details of what you tried and how it "failed".

Comment: I tried to import the file in this project https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-GettingStarted-Samples.git and it pretty much didn't work Im on dotnet 6 maui

Answer (score 1):

I made a small app with Intends based on the Demo Maui app and a zebra sample app. It works with the TC21 and is written in .Net6 Maui.

https://github.com/abeginnDev/ZebraDatawegeSampleMaui

The small Project is based on:
https://pietromaggi.com/2018/07/07/xamarin.forms--freshmvvm--datawedge/

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample project from Venkata Vimjam on GitHub. I tried it on a Zebra tc21 and it works. Never got it to run like it is described on the zebra documentation for Xamarin.
That's the Link:
https://github.com/vvimjam/MAUIZebraDataWedge

Comment: the repo u sent got an input its i dont want that ,  I wanted something like this https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-GettingStarted-Samples.git

Comment: please if someone can help ...

Comment: I know what you want, but I'm also a beginner in Maui and Xamarin. Please provide an answer if you found something useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've created barcodescan application by using DataWedge on .net MAUI. You can build it without EMDK.