# Accessing properties from different class MAUI Android application

Tags: xamarin, maui

Testing the MAUI app dev by creating a simple Android application.

I've defined an collection and UI elements in MainPage.xaml/cs.

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new();
```

Also defined an broadcast Intent receiver.

```
internal class TestReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // handle intent
        }
}
```

I want to access persons collection defined in MainPage and add items to it. There is so many pages defined what is what. App.xaml/Mainpage.xaml/MainActivity/AppShell. I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why broadcast receivers?

I suggest a different approach of your problem.
Make a class. Lets call it PersonService. Put the collection there, add method to add/remove persons. Inject it as singleton, and use it across your app.

Tomorrow when you decide not to use some static list, but database (or web-api), all you have to do is edit it at one place.

Another alternative.
Use messaging. CommunityToolkit.MAUI/MVVM have messaging system.

When you decide to go from Android to IOS? It will be much easier.

If you still want to do Android Broadcasts, please go ahead. But google search some of my alternatives. It saves me a lot of work every day, and works stable.

Comment: I'm using broadcast receivers to catch scandata from barcode scanner with datawedge of Zebra scanners.

Comment: @Shift I understand your problem, but I am not familiar with this in particular. Most of the scanners I use can be setup to send keyboard output directly, and I am perfectly ok with this. If you cant setup it or it does not fit your needs, then my answer is of no use to you, unfortunately.

Comment: @Shift Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74288158/zebra-datawedge-or-emdk-on-dotnet-maui

Comment: I'm trying to add a class like builder.Services.AddSingleton<TestService>(); but getting 'The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only.'' some reason

Comment: @Shift stupid question, are you doing this after build()? If so, move it before. Show me the code of injecting it. I can help you much better, If I see the code that fails.

Comment: crap. You are right. Hero. Thanks.